# Parse Json with array into array how nested in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have an Json body, array into array, like this:

```
{
"simulados": [
    {
        "id": "22792",
        "prova_id": "27020688",
        "materia_id": "1",
        "tipo": "2",
        "pergunta": "Com base no texto 2 e na norma padrão escrita, analise as seguintes afirmativas e assinale a alternativa correta. <br><br><span>I. A sílaba tônica marca a distinção dos tempos verbais nas palavras ‘conhecerão’ (linha 4) e ‘passaram’ (linha 19). </span><br>II. As palavras ‘bretão’ (linha 15) e ‘ancião’ (linha 20) são acentuadas por serem paroxítonas terminadas em ditongo nasal. <br>III. O til é utilizado para marcar nasalidade vocálica nas palavras ‘revitalização’ (linha 8), ‘bretão’ (linha 15) e ‘ancião’ (linha 20).",
        "numero": "8",
        "materia_desc": "Língua Portuguesa",
        "texto_id": "243",
        "texto_assoc": "#1001138#",
        "alts": "[{\"id\": 104168, \"letra\": \"a\", \"conteudo\": \"Todas as afirmativas estão corretas.\"}, {\"id\": 104169, \"letra\": \"b\", \"conteudo\": \"Somente as afirmativas I e III estão corretas.\"}, {\"id\": 104170, \"letra\": \"c\", \"conteudo\": \"Somente as afirmativas I e II estão corretas.\"}, {\"id\": 104171, \"letra\": \"d\", \"conteudo\": \"Somente a afirmativa III está correta.\"}, {\"id\": 104172, \"letra\": \"e\", \"conteudo\": \"Somente as afirmativas II e III estão corretas.\"}]"
    }
```

How i can nested this JSON in flutter, i can get data into array "simulados" but no in alts (array )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because first run of `jsonDecode()` parses `"alts"` as a string, and if you see, `"alts"` wraps a valid json array inside string. You can do one of the following:

1. Parse `"alts"` again with jsonDecode(), which will then return a List
2. Or if you can change the strucure of the json, remove quotations(" ") around `"alts"` value, so it gets parsed as a List when parsing the first time.

Comment: Nice, but how i can show data list, i use data['something in Json'] to show response, but i use

Comment: That's not how you traverse a List, that'll work for a Map but not a List. You could access List elements by iterating over them like, list.forEach((element) => print(element)), Or you could directly access an element at a particular index like this, list[0]